# Strange effect when combining cycle and bend left option in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to draw a water droplet in TikZ. Here's my code so far:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[
    left color=blue!50,
    right color=cyan!30,
    shading angle=130,
    draw=none,
    rounded corners,
    line join=round]
(0,0) ++ (30:1) arc (30:-210:1)
to[rounded corners=0,bend right=5] (90:1.5)
to[bend right=0] cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

And here's the output:

[image]

As you can notice, there is a strange effect: a little "spur" which I've circled in red. What's weird is that the droplet is totally symmetrical. It's not like the angles are too tight, it looks fine on the left side. What's stranger still is that after experimenting a bit, having the `to` option (instead of `--`) to connect to the beginning of the path with `cycle` *always* results in this spur, even if `bend left` or `bend right` are absent. If I change the path code to:

```
(0,0) ++ (30:1) arc (30:-210:1) -- (90:1.5) -- cycle;
```

then the problem goes away, but then I lose the `bend right` effect, which I wanted.

Any idea on what's happening here? This is really baffling.

Comment: @cfr I tried that, and it appears to have the exact same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the issue is caused by attempts to switch `rounded corners` on and off. In particular, `rounded corners` is in effect for only one side of the top part of the drop.

Here are a couple of alternatives:

```
\documentclass[tikz,multi,border=10pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[
    left color=blue!50,
    right color=cyan!30,
    shading angle=130,
    draw=none,
    line join=round
  ]
  (30:1) arc (30:-210:1)
  [out=60, in=-100] to (90:1.5)
  [out=-80, in=120] to cycle;
  \begin{scope}[xshift=2.25cm]
    \draw[
      left color=blue!50,
      right color=cyan!30,
      shading angle=130,
      draw=none,
      line join=round
    ]
    (30:1) arc (30:-210:1)
    .. controls +(.25,.5) and +(-.35,-.65) .. (90:1.5)
   .. controls +(.35,-.65) and +(-.25,.5) .. cycle;
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: drops]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the last line `to[bend right=0] cycle`, removing that one gets rid of the spur. This means that the last line was "extra", at least from a quick analysis.

Honestly though, your construction of the drop is really weird. I mean you're starting from the spur basically, doing an arc, then the top section to close again on the spur. Isn't it simpler to start at the top?

Also, drops have a sort of elongated shape, because of gravity, so an arc might not be the most realistic choice here.

I created another drop for comparison with the fixed version of the original one.

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

% original
\draw[
    left color=blue!50,
    right color=cyan!30,
    shading angle=130,
    draw=none,
    rounded corners,
    line join=round]
 (30:1) arc (30:-210:1)
to[rounded corners=0,bend right=5] (90:1.5)
%to[bend right=0] cycle
;

% Alenanno's version :D
\begin{scope}[xshift=3cm]
\fill[
    left color=blue!50,
    right color=cyan!30,
    shading angle=130,
    rounded corners=2mm] 
    (0,1.5) 
    to[bend right=1] ++ (.6,-.7)
    to[out=-60,in=-120, looseness=6] (-.6,.8)
    to[bend right=1] cycle;
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Try changing `none` to `red` in the original drop and you'll see that the last line is not superfluous. The reason it works to omit it is because TikZ completes the path in order to fill it, as best it can. Since it then uses a straight line (I think), the weird effects caused by the combination of `rounded corners` and the `to` path don't apply. (And maybe the switch off of rounding continues in this case - I'm not exactly certain.)

Comment: Good point about the artificiality of `arc` in the alternative rendering, though.

Comment: @cfr Thank you, first of all. :D Second, I did add `red` but it draws the path as I expected it to do, I think I'm missing what you were referring to. I was almost expecting something weird with the `\draw` option. :D

Comment: You don't get [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/U7fUo.png)? That's what I get.

Comment: I should have said in the first drop rather than the original. I meant the original one with your fix rather than the original unfixed one.

Comment: @cfr ah ok, I get that with my fix yes. Now I understand why that's working.

Comment: So I don't think your diagnosis is right: there's no spur in the OP's code. The spur is the result of TikZ's trying to round a corner cack-handedly, I think.

Comment: @cfr I'll give it a look again tomorrow I guess. :P